# Logger.info formatting

Tags: java, selenium, java.util.logging

I'm trying to log what my test have found, but it logs a time and date every time. I need to array the log so that it may read:

> "[Date/Time] User number 1 name Test (Pass or Fail)
>
> Button (Found Not or Found) ... ... ... ...
>
> User number 2 name Test ... ... ... ... ... ...
>
> User number 3 name Test ...
>
> ... ... ... ... ..."

Here's my current code:

```
package com.centurylink.rss.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.google.common.base.Predicate;

public class checkaccess {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("AccessTest");
    private static FileHandler fh;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // This block configure the logger with handler and
            // formatter
            fh = new FileHandler("C:/SeleniumLogFiles/AccessTest.log", true);
            logger.addHandler(fh);
            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            fh.setFormatter(formatter);

            // The following statement is used to log any
            // messages
            logger.info("Button Test");

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
        String actualTitle = "";
        List<WebElement> actualButtonlist;
        Set<String> buttons = new HashSet<>();
        Map<String[], Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String[], Set<String>>();

        String[] u1 = { "firstname lastname", "username" };
        String[] u2 = { "firstname lastname", "username" };
        String[] u3 = { "firstname lastname", "username" };
        String[] u4 = { "firstname lastname", "username" };
        String[] u5 = { "firstname lastname", "username" };
        String[] u6 = { "firstname lastname", "username" };
        String[] u7 = { "firstname lastname", "username" };
        String[] u8 = { "firstname lastname", "username" };
        String[] u9 = { "firstname lastname", "username" };
        String[] u10 = { "firstname lastname", "username" };
        String[] u11 = { "firstname lastname", "username" };
        String[] u12 = { "firstname lastname", "username" };
        String[] u13 = { "firstname lastname", "username" };
        String[] u14 = { "firstname lastname", "username" };

        buttons.add("Home");
        buttons.add("Subscriptions");
        buttons.add("Content");
        buttons.add("Add Content");
        buttons.add("Review");
        buttons.add("Channels");
        buttons.add("Add Channel");
        buttons.add("Review");
        buttons.add("Groups");
        buttons.add("Add Group");
        buttons.add("Review");
        buttons.add("Users");
        buttons.add("Tools");
        buttons.add("1 Call Guide");
        buttons.add("2 Call Guide");
        buttons.add("3 Call Guide");
        buttons.add("Mart");
        buttons.add("Library");
        buttons.add("Place");
        buttons.add("Tracking Report");

        map.put(u1, buttons);
        for (String[] d : map.keySet()) {
            map.get(d);
        }
        String[] accessnames = new String[14];
        accessnames[0] = "firstname lastname";
        accessnames[1] = "firstname lastname";
        accessnames[2] = "firstname lastname";
        accessnames[3] = "firstname lastname";
        accessnames[4] = "firstname lastname";
        accessnames[5] = "firstname lastname";
        accessnames[6] = "firstname lastname";
        accessnames[7] = "firstname lastname";
        accessnames[8] = "firstname lastname";
        accessnames[9] = "firstname lastname";
        accessnames[10] = "firstname lastname";
        accessnames[11] = "firstname lastname";
        accessnames[12] = "firstname lastname";
        accessnames[13] = "firstname lastname";

        String[] values = new String[14];
        values[0] = "username";
        values[1] = "username";
        values[2] = "username";
        values[3] = "username";
        values[4] = "username";
        values[5] = "username";
        values[6] = "username";
        values[7] = "username";
        values[8] = "username";
        values[9] = "username";
        values[10] = "username";
        values[11] = "username";
        values[12] = "username";
        values[13] = "username";
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        // Initializes Loop
        int i = values.length;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

            // Declaration and instantiation of objects/variables

            String baseUrl = "http://adress_here.com";
            String expectedTitle = "Welcome " + accessnames[j];

            // Launch Firefox and direct it to the Base URL
            driver.get(baseUrl);

            // Get the text box element to type into & click submit
            WebElement userid = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
            WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='Submit']"));

            // Input into text box
            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            Action InputId = builder.moveToElement(userid).click().sendKeys(userid, values[j]).moveToElement(submit)
                    .click().build();
            InputId.perform();

            // Waits 3 seconds for page to load
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Get the actual buttons of the title & For Each Loop
            // int x = Buttons.length;
            actualButtonlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='site']/input"));
            int x = actualButtonlist.size();

            // Log access pass or fail
                        if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)) {

                            logger.info(accessnames[j] + " Access Test Pass");
                        } else {

                            logger.info(accessnames[j] + " Access Test Failed");

                        }
                        // Prints pass or fail to the console
                        // if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle))
                        // {
                        // System.out.println("Login Test Passed!");
                        // } else {
                        // System.out.println("Login Test Failed");
                        // }

            // for (WebElement actualButton : actualButtonlist) {
            Set<String> thingsFound = checkFor(actualButtonlist, buttons);
            for (String s : buttons) {
                if (thingsFound.contains(s)) {
                    logger.info(s + " found");
                } else {
                    logger.info(s + " not found");
                }
            }

            // Get the actual value of the title
            actualTitle = driver.findElement(By.id("userInfoTitle")).getText();

            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        }
        // }
        try {
            fileopener();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        driver.close();
    }

    public static Set<String> checkFor(List<WebElement> web, Set<String> things) {
        String temp = null;
        HashSet<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
        for (WebElement w : web) {
            temp = w.getAttribute("value");
            if (things.contains(temp)) {
                s.add(temp);
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static void fileopener() throws IOException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("file:C:\\SeleniumLogFiles\\AccessTest.log");
        // text file, should be opening in default text editor
        File file = new File("C:/SeleniumLogFiles/AccessTest.log");

        // first check if Desktop is supported by Platform or not
        if (!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            System.out.println("Desktop is not supported");
            return;
        }

        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if (file.exists()) {
            desktop.open(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to set the [java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)) to:
`java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%5$s %6$s%n`

and just log the [current date and time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) in the logging statement:

```
if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "{0} Access Test Pass {1,date} {1,time}",
              new Object[]{accessnames[j] , System.currentTimeMillis()});
} else {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "{0} Access Test Failed {1,date, EEE, MMM dd HH:mm:ss:S ZZZ yyyy}",
              new Object[]{accessnames[j] , System.currentTimeMillis()});
}
```